Ошибка при установке stable diffusion (pytorch)
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 435, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 516, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 90, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 465, in read
    s = self.fp.read(amt)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\socket.py", line 705, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1274, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1130, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:2548)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 167, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 369, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 481, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 348, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 47, in _iter_built
    candidate = func()
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 206, in _make_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 297, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 162, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 231, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 308, in _prepare_distribution
    return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 438, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 483, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    local_file = unpack_url(
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 165, in unpack_url
    file = get_http_url(
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 106, in get_http_url
    from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\download.py", line 147, in __call__
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 53, in _rich_progress_bar
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\utils.py", line 63, in response_chunks
    for chunk in response.raw.stream(
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 573, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 509, in read
    with self._error_catcher():
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 153, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "C:\std\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 446, in _error_catcher
    raise SSLError(e)
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:2548)


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Похоже к какому-то сайту не может законнектиться, чтобы что-то скачать. В какой момент ошибка то выходит, как ставите, что запускаете?
